# Reading HTML source from variable into HTMLUNIT

Tags: java, grails, htmlunit

All of the examples I see for htmlunit retrieve the HTML from website via a URL using **getPage**.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net");
```

I'm holding an HTML fragment in a string variable and can't find a way to give it the HTML from a variable.

I've tried casting the String to HtmlPage but that doesn't work.

```
HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) htmlFragment
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could write the HTML fragment (possibly wrapped in the standard html/head/body tags) into a temp file and use its URL for your web client.  For example (untested):

```java
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("fragment", "html");
HtmlPage startPage = webClient.getPage(tempFile.toURI().toURL().toString());
tempFile.deleteOnExit();
```

Alternatively, you might be able to [construct your own `HtmlPage`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlPage.html#HtmlPage%28java.net.URL,%20com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebResponse,%20com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebWindow%29) with a phony URL and ad-hoc [`WebResponse`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebResponse.html) and [`WebWindow`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebWindow.html) but that might require a lot of hacking.

Comment: Thanks, this may be my best alternative.